# load .Rda file into a slot of a S4 R Class during its construction

Tags: r, oop, import, r-s4

Is there any way I can import a .rda file as a default value of a S4 Class slot during the declaration of the default prototype?

Let's say I have a `data/myRDAdata.rda` file in my R package. I would like to create a S4 R object as follows:

```
bed_object <- setClass(
# name
"bed_object",

 slots = c(chr= "character"),

 prototype = list(chr = c("chr1", "etc..")), #ADD HERE IMPORT FOR A .Rda file

 validity=function(object){
           return(TRUE)
 }
)
```

and have it load `data(myRDAdata)` in chr during the prototype declaration.

Thanks for anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by defining an `initialize` method for your class which reads in a default file. Using this class as an example,

```
bed_object <- setClass(
    "bed_object",
    slots = c(data.file = "character",
              data = "data.frame"
    ),

    prototype = list(
        ## system.file("data/default-data.Rdata", package = "mypackage")
        data.file = "default-data.Rdata",
        data = data.frame()
    ), 

    validity = function(object) {
        if (!file.exists("default-data.Rdata")) {
            stop(sprintf("Could not find %s!", object@data.file))
        }

        tmp.env <- new.env()
        .x <- try({
            suppressWarnings(load(object@data.file, envir = tmp.env))
        }, silent = TRUE)

        if (inherits(.x, "try-error")) {
            stop(sprintf("Could not read %s!", object@data.file))
        }

        TRUE
    }
)
```

The `initialize` method might look something like this:

```
setMethod("initialize", "bed_object", function(.Object, ...) {
    .Object <- callNextMethod()
    if (validObject(.Object)) {
        tmp.env <- new.env()
        x <- load(.Object@data.file, envir = tmp.env)

        .Object@data <- tmp.env[[x[1]]]
        invisible(.Object)
    }
})
```

Testing this out,

```
Df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
save(Df, file = "default-data.Rdata")

## default
b1 <- new("bed_object")
b1@data
#  x  y
#1 1  6
#2 2  7
#3 3  8
#4 4  9
#5 5 10

## invalid data file
b2 <- new("bed_object", data.file = "xyz.Rdata")
#Error in validityMethod(object) : Could not read xyz.Rdata!
```

---

A couple of remarks:

- You'll want to replace my default file `default-data.Rdata` with whatever you are shipping with the package; something like `system.file("data/default-data.Rdata", package = "mypackage")`
- The `validity` method isn't necessary, but it doesn't hurt to have either

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for you help!